# IE hangs when opening a file from a HTA, the first time. Works OK after that, if it can open one

Tags: internet-explorer, hta

I have a *.hta file that's going to be autorun by a DVD.  It has links like:

```
<a href="files/myfile.pdf>My File</a>
```

Quite simple and everything works fine.  When a user clicks a link, the *.pdf opens in a new instance of IE.  Except when it's burnt to a DVD.  Then, the user clicks a link, IE opens and nothing happens.

This is probably a bug or local security setting that has no remedy but if someone has seen this before?

P.S: I also tried putting the files on a memory stick that has a read-only switch, to simulate being on a CD, but was unable to reproduce the error.  This may end up taking a lot of CDs.

Comment: This is a very odd error: If the whole lot is burned to a CD, the links to files won't open.  If it's a mounted ISO, the links work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've just bumped into that. I don't have a solution, but I can share some details.

There's an HTA application shell with an iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>My HTA Application</title>
   <HTA:APPLICATION ID="application"
                    CONTEXTMENU="no"
                    SELECTION="no" />
   <style type="text/css">
      body { margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
      #frame-main { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <iframe id="frame-main"
           frameborder="0"
           APPLICATION="yes"
           src="web/index.htm">
   </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

that hosts a simple HTML document with some hyperlinks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>Home</title>
   <base target="_blank" />
</head>
<body>
   <a href="data/doc.pdf">Open PDF</a>
   <a href="data/">Go to folder</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Works as expected from the local drive. When run from a CD:

- clicking any of the hyperlinks for the first time opens a blank IE window
- clicking any of them for the second time opens the URL as expected
- clicking any of them for the third time does nothing until focus is moved away from the window

When the HTML file is opened directly in the browser, everything works fine.

I've reproduced this on two PCs with Windows 7 (x86 and x64) and Internet Explorer 8. On two Windows XP machines it worked just fine (no details on the version of MSIE).

Comment: That's pretty much exactly the behaviour that I saw.  I eventually use the .hta to cause an IE window to open and then write to that window's document.